# sudo E option does not work?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, root

Seems to me that if I write a shell script in `$HOME/path/to/script/myscript`, and `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/path/to/script/` then `sudo -E myscript` should run the script right?

[From sudo man page:](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo.man.html)

> ‑E
>   The ‑E (preserve environment) option indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables. The security policy may return an error if the ‑E option is specified and the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.

But `sudo -E script` can't find the command. I know I can just add `/absolute/path/to/script/` to the files that determine the `PATH` variable for `sudo env`, but that's not the approach I want to take.

**To address the comments:**

**@H2CO3**: I have seen `sudo sudo` floating around the net, and it bugs me tremendously, it's literally saying "Give me superuser permissions to run superuser". I don't know if it would solve the problem, but it seems like a fundamentally flawed approach. Then again I started using linux/bsd systems back in the mid 90's so I take issue with just the `sudo` command itself.
**@rici**: The script does have executable permissions, but that's definitely something to check whenever something doesn't run in *nix systems =)

Comment: Maybe it needs more permissions... try `sudo sudo`... Oh well...

Comment: Did you make sure your script file is executable?

Comment: Most distros of linux/unix no longer require CLI to accomplish any `general computing` task. Just because sudo CAN be used for general computing, does not make it the primary purpose of this tool. Python CAN be (and was often) used as a calculator, but it is obviously not `general computing software`. I use sudo to execute tools that are useful exclusively for development, and scripts I wrote. As such, I kindly request that you reevalute either the content of  http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, http://superuser.com/help/on-topic, or your decision to mark this question as off topic.

Comment: to further my case, by your description of why my question is off topic, the following questions should [have] be[en] marked off topic [long] ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ 18708087, 13828364, 12970199, 7969540, 257616

Answer (score 11, accepted):

/etc/sudoers by default has a setting to reset the environment. And also defines a default secure_path which is in effect when you run sudo -E [cmd].

You will need to edit the /etc/sudoers file and add 'env_keep' and mention the variables you want to preserve.

Default env_keep += "PATH"

but before this comment out the secure_path line. Then try your command via sudo -E.

Comment: `comment out the secure_path line` this did the trick, thank you!

Comment: Use `sudo visudo` to edit the sudoers file. It validates your changes and might prevent that you lock yourself out.. [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo#Tools_and_similar_programs)