# Bash script not found although it is in the $PATH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

On LMDE-based laptop I have a script `upgrade.sh` which only runs the following commands:

```
#!/bin/sh

apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

The script is in the `/home/francois/scripts` directory. I can easily run it from within this directory. It just works. Now I run the following commands:

```
$ sudo ln -s /home/francois/scripts /opt/scripts
$ sudo ln -s /opt/scripts /usr/local/bin/scripts
```

and create file `/etc/profile.d/myscripts.sh`

with just one line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/scripts
```

I type

```
$ echo $PATH
```

and see that it contains `/usr/local/bin/scripts`

But when I run

```
$ sudo upgrade.sh
```

from any directory the system says that `the command not found`

`ls -l` shows `-rwxr-xr-x 1 francois francois` ...

Comment: Is your script actually marked executable? And you need a shebang for it to be executed by anything other than a shell. [Edit] the question to show file permissions (ie. output of `ls -l upgrade.sh`).

Comment: ...which is to say, this is fairly likely to be a duplicate of [How do I run a shell script without using `sh` or `bash` commands?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779951/how-do-i-run-a-shell-script-without-using-sh-or-bash-commands), if it isn't duplicative of a `sudo`-specific question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sudo changes PATH - why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why)

Comment: ...note that a *shell* will let you get away without a shebang line (`#!/bin/bash` or similar), but when launching software from any non-shell program (and `sudo` is not a shell!), it's strictly required.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You can definitely run a script that doesn't have a shebang with sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Sudo doesn't inherit the caller's environment variables. `$PATH` is one of those variables.

To make it inherit the environment variables of the shell it's invoked from, run it as `sudo -E [cmd]`

Comment: Thank you. But I just tried it and still get: `sudo: upgrade.sh: command not found`

Comment: are you sure of this? the response provided looks to be OK since this is the way envs are passed on sudo commands.

Comment: @MaurizioBenedetti Doesn't work for me, `sudo env PATH="$PATH" COMMAND` does though.

Comment: This may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748045/sudo-e-option-does-not-work

Comment: Yes, I'm baffled myself.  I go to `/home/francois/scripts` and run script from there and it works. But after going to `'..'` it is not found!